# 2006 caravab 3.3 high rpm miss idle is good

Tags: engine, grand-caravan

I have a 06 3.3 dodge caravan that has a miss in the higher RPM range which also makes the transmission seam to slip, I have read a bunch of comments and don't want to just throw parts at it. it had a code for cyl #2 misfire, I cleaned the plug and the code didn't come back but it still has a miss at the higher RPM range. I put a cheap harbor frieght spark tester on each cylinder and each one has a spark. it is a yellow spark though. did notice with the tester in line with the engine running that the light flickered about the same time it missed. It did this on each cylinder. I just got the van from a post office auction and it had 99,000 miles on it but all local city driving. I looked at the wires going into the coil pack and they were not burnt like some say they might.
thanks in advance, from what I have seen on problems like this people seem to throw a lot of parts hoping something fixes it, the van seemed to have been maintained well.

Comment: You could have someone put an oscilloscope on it and do a primary/secondary ignition test to see what the problem is. Otherwise you’re probably gonna end up throwing parts. You could try swapping wires around to see if the problem moves.

Comment: thanks, I have tried the plug wires with no change. I will try to find a oscilloscope next.